# Use translations in newtheorem defintion

Tags: environments, babel, newtheorem, translations

How can I use the translations package to define multi-lingual newtheorem environments as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel} 
\usepackage{translations}
\usepackage[thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}

\DeclareTranslationFallback{example}{Example}
\DeclareTranslation{German}{example}{Beispiel}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{Example}[Theorem]{\GetTranslation{example}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Example}
    content...
\end{Example}

\end{document}
```

I just get an error

> undefined control sequence

Comment: Which control sequence is undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to `ntheorem`: add `\protect` in front of `\GetTranslation`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{translations}
\usepackage[thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}

\DeclareTranslationFallback{example}{Example}
\DeclareTranslation{German}{example}{Beispiel}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{Example}[Theorem]{\protect\GetTranslation{example}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Example}
    content...
\end{Example}

\end{document}
```

[image]